# mypy overload function with numpy ndarray and pandas dataframe (signature parameter type(s) are the same or broader)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that does some arithmetic stuff (quantile normalization) over either a numpy array or pandas dataframe. When you put in a ndarray, you should get back a ndarray, and when you put in a pandas dataframe you should get back a dataframe:

```
from typing import Union, overload


@overload
def quantile_normalize(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame: ...
@overload
def quantile_normalize(data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray: ...


def quantile_normalize(data: Union[pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray]) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray]:
    pass
```

However when I try to test this with mypy it complains:

```
qnorm/quantile_normalize.py:72: error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader
```

The problems and answers so far I have found related to this issue all seem to be related to optional input/output and None types. A pandas dataframe and a numpy array are related, however, they should be distinguishible by mypy.

Comment: Do you have type stubs for `numpy`/`pandas` available? E.g. run `pip install data-science-types`, remove ignores for missing `numpy`/`pandas` type hints and check whether the error persists.

Comment: @hoefling that indeed fixed the problem. Please submit this as an answer and I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a library is missing type hints, every import will resolve to `Any`. Both `numpy` and `pandas` aren't PEP 526 conform (not offering any type hints) and have no stubs in `typeshed`, so both `pd.DataFrame` and `np.ndarray` will resolve to `Any`, thus both overloads resolve to `def quantile_normalize(data: Any) -> Any: ...`. To fix the issue, add stubs for `numpy` and `pandas`.

Either use existing type stubs - I use `data-science-types` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/), [GitHub](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types)) which offer stubs for `numpy`, `pandas` and `matplotlib`:

```
$ pip install data-science-types
```

Now `pd.DataFrame` and `np.ndarray` will be correctly resolved when running `mypy`. This will also provide you better code completions in every IDE that supports PEP 526 (e.g. Visual Studio Code or WingIDE) for free.

Or, if you can't/don't want to add the stub package, write your own minimal stubs, e.g.

```
# _typeshed/pandas/__init__.pyi

from typing import Any


def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete

class DataFrame:
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete
```

and

```
# _typeshed/numpy/__init__.pyi

from typing import Any


def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete

class ndarray:
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete
```

and run `MYPYPATH=_typeshed mypy ...`.